# How to check if multivalued field contains values MS Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am having an issue with multivalued fields in Microsoft Access 2007.

I would like to select values in a check box list and, based on these values, query for items where the multivalued column **contains** all these values.

```
SELECT i.ID, i.Responsibility.Value
FROM tb_Items i
WHERE <<<what should I put here?>>>;
```

I need to fill the *where* clause with values from a check box list and check if the multivalued column in the table (tb_Items.Responsability, in that case) contains these values.

How am I supposed to do that?

Edited:

I have a check box list with the values filled, allowing me to check it.

i.Responsibility is a multivalued field in the database table. When I query this table using *Select i.Responsibility.Value from tb_Items i* the data column i.Responsibility is returned void to me **if** the multivalued field has more than one option selected, or it is returned the only selected value, **if**, of course, it has only one value selected.

My questions is specifically how can I make a *where* clause that returns to me whether the multivalued field **in** the table **contains** a set of values. By **contains** I mean "has selected". For example, if for a given registry in the table the multivalued field has options A, B and C selected, I want to be able to query whether A and B are selected for example, and it must return true for this registry. I can even enter these values manually in the query, and worry about how to retrieve them from the check box list afterwards. My main concern right now is how to write the query.

Comment: So, do you have the combobox built yet? I'm confused.

Comment: You can't 'multi-select' items in a combobox... do you mean listbox?

Comment: `i.Responsability.Value` <<< I don't think you need `.Value` on the end here. You refer to "these values"... can you tell us what these values are? What fields they come from?

Answer (score 0):

This depends a little bit on your specific situation. It sounds like you're trying to run the query from a form, so one approach would be to iterate the values in the combo-box firstm and then store them in a hidden textbox on your form. Have the WHERE condition of the query reference this "fixed up field", simplifying the query.

Here is a good article on the subject:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-multivalued-fields-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31?CorrelationId=4759a5d8-3c1d-40da-9670-da60c3833944&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm7

If you can explain your exact situation a bit more I'm sure I can help.

Thanks...

Comment: Hi @DanielG, I have updated the question with more details. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I found the correct way of doing so. Is it simply using concatenated AND clauses like WHERE field = 'A' AND field = 'B' AND field = 'C'...